# Error en ejecución de sentencia sql

Tags: sql-server, sql

Tengo la siguiente sentencia la cual a ejecutar cumple con lo solicitado que es el de mostrar los 56 resultados en ese periodo.

SQL

```
SELECT 
SUEM_EMPL AS SME,
SUELQUIN_EMPL AS SQE,
OTROS_EMPL AS SO 
FROM HIS_ROL_ADM_SUELDOS WHERE MES_EMPL = 1
```

Resultado
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pero ahora que añado otra tabla en un inner join que me permite mostrar los datos del empleado pero ahora solo me arrojan 8 resultados

SQL

```
SELECT E.ADM_CEDULA AS CEDULA,
        MAX(ISNULL(E.ADM_APELLIDO,'')) + SPACE(1) + MAX(ISNULL(E.ADM_NOMBRE,'')) AS OBRERO,
        E.ADM_SECCION AS SECCION,
        A.SUEM_EMPL AS SME,
        A.SUELQUIN_EMPL AS SQE,
        A.OTROS_EMPL AS SO 
        FROM HIS_ROL_ADM_SUELDOS AS A
        INNER JOIN TBL_ADMIN AS E 
        ON E.ADM_CEDULA =  A.CEDU_EMPL AND (A.MES_EMPL = 1)
        GROUP BY 
        E.ADM_CEDULA,E.ADM_SECCION,A.SUEM_EMPL,A.SUELQUIN_EMPL,A.OTROS_EMPL
        ORDER BY OBRERO
```

Resultados

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Que podría estar realizando de manera errónea?.

De antemano agradezco su ayuda.

Comment: añade datos de prueba para poder replicar más fácil el problema

Comment: Y si usas LEFT JOIN en vez de inner ?

Comment: Comentarios: (a) `(A.MES_EMPL = 1)`debe ir en el `where` no en el `ON` (b) El `inner` solo te traerá las filas coincidentes entre ambas tablas, es decir las que `ADM.CEDULA` sea igual a `CEDU_EMPL`. ¿En `TBL_ADMIN` tienes una fila por cada `CEDU_EMPL`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Siguiendo las sugerencias de cada uno y revisando a fondo, el error que encontré fue que en el periodo que estaba consultando la información algunas cédulas no empezaban con el 0 razón por la cual al hacer el match con la tabla admin no coincidían.

Adjunto el codigo hecho con el where y con el inner join

WHERE

```
  SELECT TBL_ADMIN.ADM_CEDULA AS CEDULA,
MAX(ISNULL(TBL_ADMIN.ADM_APELLIDO,'')) + SPACE(1) + MAX(ISNULL(TBL_ADMIN.ADM_NOMBRE,'')) AS OBRERO,
TBL_ADMIN.ADM_SECCION AS SECCION,
HIS_ROL_ADM_SUELDOS.SUEM_EMPL AS SME,
HIS_ROL_ADM_SUELDOS.SUELQUIN_EMPL AS SQE,
HIS_ROL_ADM_SUELDOS.OTROS_EMPL AS SO
FROM HIS_ROL_ADM_SUELDOS , TBL_ADMIN
WHERE  TBL_ADMIN.ADM_CEDULA =  HIS_ROL_ADM_SUELDOS.CEDU_EMPL
GROUP BY 
TBL_ADMIN.ADM_CEDULA,TBL_ADMIN.ADM_SECCION,HIS_ROL_ADM_SUELDOS.SUEM_EMPL,HIS_ROL_ADM_SUELDOS.SUELQUIN_EMPL,HIS_ROL_ADM_SUELDOS.OTROS_EMPL
ORDER BY OBRERO
```

INNER JOIN

```
 SELECT TBL_ADMIN.ADM_CEDULA AS CEDULA,
MAX(ISNULL(TBL_ADMIN.ADM_APELLIDO,'')) + SPACE(1) + MAX(ISNULL(TBL_ADMIN.ADM_NOMBRE,'')) AS OBRERO,
TBL_ADMIN.ADM_SECCION AS SECCION,
HIS_ROL_ADM_SUELDOS.SUEM_EMPL AS SME,
HIS_ROL_ADM_SUELDOS.SUELQUIN_EMPL AS SQE,
HIS_ROL_ADM_SUELDOS.OTROS_EMPL AS SO 
FROM HIS_ROL_ADM_SUELDOS 
INNER JOIN TBL_ADMIN  
ON  TBL_ADMIN.ADM_CEDULA =  HIS_ROL_ADM_SUELDOS.CEDU_EMPL AND(HIS_ROL_ADM_SUELDOS.MES_EMPL = 1)
GROUP BY 
TBL_ADMIN.ADM_CEDULA,TBL_ADMIN.ADM_SECCION,HIS_ROL_ADM_SUELDOS.SUEM_EMPL,HIS_ROL_ADM_SUELDOS.SUELQUIN_EMPL,HIS_ROL_ADM_SUELDOS.OTROS_EMPL
ORDER BY OBRERO
```

De antemano agradezco a todos por su gran ayuda y respuestas.

Answer (score 0):

Basándome solamente en tus consultas no veo nada que pueda reducir así los datos, por el contrario tal vez no estés haciendo nada mal y resulte que solo hay 8 coincidencias en : E.ADM_CEDULA =  A.CEDU_EMPL AND (A.MES_EMPL = 1). Seria bueno que revisaras si efectivamente esos 56 registros de tu primer consulta tienen coincidencia en la otra tabla.

Comment: Que tal @stre_leon , añadi unas imagenes en donde se muestra el resultado de cada uno y como tu dices no veo problema pero el resultado no es el esperado.

Comment: que tal Carrobe90, ¿Los campos E.ADM_CEDULA y A.CEDU_EMPL estan relacionados con llaves foraneas?. Pregunto esto  solo para descartar que NO haya cedulas en HIS_ROL_ADM_SUELDOS, que no existen en TBL_ADMIN.